# BIOS message about electrical fault after not plugging in router properly on same 4-plug extension

Tags: bios, power-supply, post

When I first set up this system (bought new in 2022) I had the computer, monitor, speakers, and router plugged into one four-plug power extension. I didn't realise, but the router was only half plugged in to the socket. The computer booted up fine and I spent 10 minutes creating a user account and setting everything up. I was able to download some programs but the internet was flaky. At one point the screen went totally black while in the middle of using it so I figured something was up.

I eventually realised that the router wasn't plugged in properly, pushed the plug all the way in and rebooted. On reboot there was a BIOS message saying something to the effect of the electrical supply had been unstable, worded as if it was just an FYI, with a "press any key to continue".

Has anyone encountered this message before or know what it means, in terms of how the flag gets set and what possible damage could have been done? Or where I would find that info - I've googled for "AMI UEFI BIOS manual" as well as the message generally but couldn't find anything.

Specs:

- No-brand PSU
- Asus HS10M-E motherboard with AMI UEFI BIOS version 1203
- Intel Core i3
- 8GB RAM
- 240GB SSD

Comment: “Has anyone encountered this message before or know what it means” - It simply means your computer was unexpectedly shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Shut down. Orderly is best, but if not, disconnect the power.

Wait at least a minute.

Check and double check all power connections.

Start the computer.

Does it start properly?  If so ignore the error you posted and carry on.

If not, start in BIOS and see if you can troubleshoot the error.

You may need to reload BIOS.